# Problema com PSR-4 e autoload do composer

Tags: composer, php-autoload, php

Estou tendo um problema com o autoload do composer, a estrutura e código estão todos certos, só que ele não está achando a classe.

Já atualizei os autoloads pelo bash e nada... alguém sabe o que possa ser?

```
{
    "name": "celestino/ecommerce",
    "description": "PHP 7 Ecommerce",
    "type": "project",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Lucas Celestino",
            "email": "vtecommerce@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer":"5.2.*",
        "rain/raintpl":"3.0.0",
        "slim/slim":"2.0"
    },
    "autoload":{
        "psr-4": {
            "Cap\\":"vendor\\cap\\php-classes\\src"
        }
    }
}
```

Esse é meu index.php onde estou chamando a classe:

```
<?php
require_once("vendor\autoload.php");

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/', function ()
{
    $sql = new Cap\DB\Sql();
    $sql->teste();
});


$app->run();


?>
```

E essa é a minha classe que estou chamando.

Estrutura da pasta: ecommerce\vendor\cap\php-classes\src\DB

```
<?php

namespace DB;

class Sql
{
    public function teste()
    {
        echo "Funcionando";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A primeira parte do seu *namespace* precisa ser igual ao definido no composer.json. A partir dessa primeira parte, o PSR-4 segue a sua estrutura de diretórios. Cuidado com letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, isso é diferente para alguns sistemas operacionais e pode causar problemas de classe não encontrada.

Troque o *namespace* da sua classe para:

```
<?php

namespace Cap\DB;

class Sql
{
    public function teste()
    {
        echo "Funcionando";
    }
}
```

O caminho onde estão salvos suas dependências também podem ser corrigidas. Utilize a barra convencional para separar os espaços. Mesmo no Windows a barra vai funcionar.

Sobre seu código estar dentro do vendor, não acho uma boa ideia salvar ali dentro códigos que não são gerenciados pelo composer. Geralmente esse diretório não é versionado e você pode esquecer de versionar o seu código.

```
"autoload":{
    "psr-4": {
        "Cap\\": "php-classes/cap/src/"
    }
}
```